# Error in resolving package dependency swiftUI project

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, xcode13.3

Dependencies could not be resolved because root depends on 'googleappmeasurement' 9.0.0.
'googleappmeasurement' 9.0.0 cannot be used because 'googleappmeasurement' 9.0.0 depends on 'nanopb' 2.30908.0..<2.30909.0 and root depends on 'nanopb' 2.30909.0..<2.30910.0.
that is my error message, can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same problem. I cloned two different projects from GitHub and am getting this error in both projects independently... Both projects were originally created in Xcode 13 so different Xcode versions isn't the issue.

Comment: @Eric, could you provide a link to a project (better simpler one) which you cloned and observe issue, to test?

Comment: @Asperi I have discovered the cause, and the solution. See my answer below if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SDK version 8.9.1 and everything working fine, If you executed the `Resolve Package Versions` and still not working. you can try the command `Reset Package Caches` from Project navigator scroll down right click on `Package Dependencies` then choose the command. that will clear all caches for all installed packages then re-install them again. if that not working i suggest you to use version 8.9.1 till Firebase fix the issue.

Comment: Explain this better. Your directions are hard to follow

Comment: I was able to go `File` > `Packages` > `Reset Package Caches`, but it didn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the problem has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975125/xcode-failed-to-resolve-dependency-firebase). It occurs when importing Firebase using Swift Package Manager and setting to track "master" instead of a specific release version.

Answer (score -1):

Got same error and solved, check attached image, this most likely packages usage misconfiguration, as follows:

1-perhaps you are working on a branch with different Xcode version than the other developer who installed the package.

2-Perhaps some package is conflicted being used twice, by so some dependencies are duplicated.

Well to solve this you gotta try either to match the Xcode version used while installing the packages, or to remove the package that makes errors(like Firebase here), and try adding that package again your side.

[image: Check before and after the fix]